# How can I get the facebook picture of other users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I am using the facebook sdk for unity. If I use the facebook api to receive the image of the user that is logged in it works without problems with the command line:

http://graph.facebook.com/{userid}/picture

In my game two players can meet. In this case I transfer the user ID of player A to player B and the other way around to they can download the profile pictures of the other user and show them in the game. But I only receive a gif file with the default facebook picture but not the users picture. Even worse this default picture is on a server that unity can't access.

Weirdly enough. If I don't log the user in and use the public user id they can download the pictures without problem. But it stops working after the FB.Login method is used.

How can I show the user the profile pictures of other players in the game? Do I have to use a different command to receive the pictures of other users?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It seems that AFTER you login using the facebook api blocks all access to users that aren't users of your app in version 2.2. So you can only access other people that use your app with an user id that is only created for your app.
ALSO: It seems normal user can't access test user. Two test user can see each other and two normal user can but the combination doesn't work.

Correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Then you should call FB API core method like this:

```
FB.API(userID + "?fields=picture.width(100).height(100)", HttpMethod.GET, PhotoCallbackMethod);
```